# How to assign a Run to a text property, programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know in XAML we can do...

```
<TextBlock FontSize="18">
   This is my text <LineBreak/>
   <Run FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold">My big bold text</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Question is, how can I assign a Run into a text (string) property, programmatically?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you look at `TextBlock` you will see that ContentProperty is set to `Inlines`

```
[Localizability(LocalizationCategory.Text), ContentProperty("Inlines")]
public class TextBlock : FrameworkElement, ...
```

This means that you will add `Inline` elements to the property `Inlines` for everyting added between the opening and closing tag of `TextBlock`.

So the c# equivalent to your Xaml is

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.FontSize = 18;
textBlock.Inlines.Add("This is my text");
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
Run run = new Run("My big bold text");
run.FontSize = 24;
run.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
textBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
```

Comment: No need for a decompiler, the documentation can tell you that too (both in the form of an attribute and prose).

Comment: @svick: Very true. I used reflector just to be able to paste it in. But that surely isn't the only way, I'll remove that part from the answer

Comment: @svick: Also, I'll take the chance to learn something here. I can see it at MSDN but what did you mean by attribute or prose?

Comment: I meant that you can either look at the syntax section and see the `[ContentPropertyAttribute]`, or read the Remarks: “A `TextBlock` can contain a string in its `Text` property or `Inline` flow content elements […] in its `Inlines` property.”

Comment: BTW, I think this is a good example of code where object and collection initializers could make it more readable.