# C# WPF Textblock different font color per line

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-style

I am trying to make each line of text on a WPF textblock display in a different color. I have the following code which makes the entire block's font color purple because that's the last color it's set to. How can I make it so each potion is displayed in a different color?

```
    private void btnShowPotions_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        tbPotionInfo.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
        tbPotionInfo.Text = smallPotion.Name + "(" + smallPotion.AffectValue + ")\r\n";
        tbPotionInfo.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
        tbPotionInfo.Text += mediumPotion.Name + "(" + mediumPotion.AffectValue + ")\r\n";
        tbPotionInfo.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        tbPotionInfo.Text += largePotion.Name + "(" + largePotion.AffectValue + ")\r\n";
        tbPotionInfo.Foreground = Brushes.Purple;
        tbPotionInfo.Text += extremePotion.Name + "(" + extremePotion.AffectValue + ")\r\n";
    }
```

Comment: you can make use of `Run` here

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-textblock-control-inline-formatting/ - specifically the section named RUN and SPAN.

Comment: use richtextbox and set it to readonly , or you have to setup textblock with one textbox for each color

Comment: @Thorarins you're wrong - with the usage of `Run`s or `Span`s he will be working with one `TextBlock` only. Besides - `RichTextBox` is reaaaaally slow and laggy. Have you actually tried to use it in your apps?

Comment: @Gopichandar I saw runs in a similar and question and am not sure how to implement them because the text isn't generated until the button is clicked my Xaml doesn't have any runs to edit.

Comment: Then add them in your code behind.

Comment: @SzwornyDziach Thank you. For completeness sake if you post that as an answer I'll accept it. I used the syntax here for adding runs programmatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906539/how-to-assign-a-run-to-a-text-property-programmatically

Comment: @Gopichandar is already ahead of me ;)

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch yes richtextbox is a bit slow. but run is messy and makes the code hard to maintain

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of `Run`.

Here is the sample of how to use the `Run`

```
Run run = new Run(smallPotion.Name + "(" + smallPotion.AffectValue + ")\r\n");
run.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
tbPotionInfo.Inlines.Add(run);   

run = new Run(mediumPotion.Name + "(" + mediumPotion.AffectValue + ")\r\n");
run.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
tbPotionInfo.Inlines.Add(run);        
...
```

Haven't verified but I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Use textblock like this

```
<TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Name="tbSmallPotion" Foreground="Green"/
      <TextBlock Text="tbMediumPotion"Foreground="Blue"/>
 </TextBlock>
```

and set the values

```
tbSmallPotion.Text = smallPotion.Name + "(" + smallPotion.AffectValue + ")\r\n";
tbMediumPotion.Text = mediumPotion.Name + "(" + mediumPotion.AffectValue + ")\r\n";
```

Comment: Yes this would work, I ended up going with Gopichandar's solution for the simplicity of having one textblock.