# Wpf localization dynamic Subscript for TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, textblock

I'm using MVVM pattern to bind text to `TextBlock`.
The text is defined in database with `<Subscript>` tag to define when the text is Subscript. `"Some<Subscript>subscript</Subscript>text."`

I tried using [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts), but the characters appears too small, and hard to read.

I couldn't find a direct way to do this. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Attached properties fixed my problem in the most MVVM friendly way.
You get the text and add to the TextBlock Inlines as you want.

Attached property c#:

```
public static class TextBlockAp {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SubscriptTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "SubscriptText", typeof(string), typeof(TextboxAttachedProperty), new PropertyMetadata(OnSubscriptTextPropertyChanged));

    public static string GetSubscriptText(DependencyObject obj) {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(SubscriptTextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSubscriptText(DependencyObject obj, string value) {
        obj.SetValue(SubscriptTextProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnSubscriptTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        try {
            var value = e.NewValue as string;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return;
            var textBlock = (TextBlock)d;

            var startTag = "<Subscript>";
            var endTag = "</Subscript>";
            var subscript = String.Empty;
            if (value.Contains(startTag) && value.Contains(endTag)) {
                int index = value.IndexOf(startTag) + startTag.Length;
                subscript = value.Substring(index, value.IndexOf(endTag) - index);
            }

            var text = value.Split(new[] { startTag }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(text[0]);
            Run run = new Run($" {subscript}") { BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Subscript, FontSize = 9 };
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (ExceptionUtilities.UiPolicyException(ex)) throw;
        }
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<TextBlock ap:TextBlockAp.SubscriptText="{Binding MyProperty}" />
```

It needs more refactoring to work correctly, but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

When you know that there is a subscription Tag you may use several Runs within your TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run />
   <Run />
</TextBlock>
```

I think you do not know the exact position of the subscripted text, right? So, why not just analyze your input and creating a new Run programatically? The Runs with the normal text have another size than Runs with subscripted text.

If you need help with adding Runs programatically just have a look at this StackOverflow post:
[How to assign a Run to a text property, programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906539/how-to-assign-a-run-to-a-text-property-programmatically)

I know this is not the best way in MVVM to define XAML controls in your ViewModel, but thats the fastest way to reach better legibility.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your reply. You are correct, I don't know the position of the subscript. and I'm trying to avoid any UI Controls inside my ViewModel.

Comment: No problem. This might be just the way to go when no other solution helps ;-)